# UltimateListCtrl shows non Hyperlink-Items as Hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, wxpython, listctrl

I currently have the problem that when I put the "hypertext" flag with the method "SetHyperText" to an item , then the rest of items are shown as hyperlinks even though they are not.

Code:

```
for ids in [2, 3]:
    item = self.list.GetItem(ids, 1)
    item.SetHyperText(True)
    self.list.SetItem(item)
```

[hyperlink text](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-3HL-03O7KMw/VbtVXAKOLAI/AAAAAAAAAEU/wPSaCNjbu3Y/s1600/2015-07-31%2B12_59_59-UltimateListCtrl%2Bin%2Bwx.LC_REPORT%2Bmode.png)
[As hyperlink showed non hyperlink text](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gRjRkkNej0M/VbtVdqyv_kI/AAAAAAAAAEc/Mb1Bw1nHZvQ/s1600/2015-07-31%2B13_00_17-UltimateListCtrl%2Bin%2Bwx.LC_REPORT%2Bmode.png)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for ids in [2, 3]:
    self.list.SetItemHyperText(ids, 1)
```